# git Permission denied on Docker container with private key

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, openssh, ssh-agent

I created a Docker container and run it via shell script which contains this execution:

```
docker run --rm -it \
        --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
        --network host \
        -e USER=$USER \
        -e HOME=$HOME \
        -h $HOSTNAME \
        -v /tmp:/tmp \
        -v /home/$USER:/home/$USER \
        -v ~/.ssh:/home/$USER/.ssh:ro \
        -e USERNAME=$USERNAME \
        -w /home/$USER \
        $IMAGE_NAME \
        /bin/bash
```

Therefore, I think there is neither right access nor key existence issue. However, if I go to my git working directory which has been cloned with ssh before. I cannot authenticate.

```
git pull -v
git@mygitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Printing out the output of `ssh -tv git@mygitlab.com` I see these differences:
Without Docker container

```
...
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:20AHxx agent
debug1: Will attempt key: gitlab ED25519 SHA256:fEqoFK agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
....
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:20AHxx agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: gitlab ED25519 SHA256:fEqoFK agent
debug1: Server accepts key: gitlab ED25519 SHA256:fEqoFK agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

In the Docker container:

```
...
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:20AHxx
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering public key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:20AHxx
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@mygitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Shall I need something to do with the ssh-agent?

Comment: According to the log it does not accept the id_ed25519 key on the host either, instead it is accepting a key named `gitlab` which is not presented to the server when running in the container. I would guess that this is registered with the `ssh-agent` on the host.

Comment: This seems likke you're trying to run something "in a Docker container" but that's indistinguishable from running it on the host system (with host files, host user IDs, host networking, host ssh keys, _etc._).  Can you run this `git` command from a host shell instead?  Why is Docker involved here?

Comment: Trivial, but useful in the future: you wanted `ssh -Tv`. The `-T` means *don't bother with tty*; with `-t` it means *demand tty*, which won't work (but will still get you the info you cared about here, so that's why this is trivial).

Comment: @DavidMaze: the container will re-route file system, network, and/or other requests depending on the container setup. Typically a docker setup has the file system rewired, so that `/home/me/.ssh/` files differ from the host version of `/home/me/.ssh/` files. *In this case* he's got `/home/me` transferred straight across, so that's not the problem ... but he doesn't have the ssh agent files.

Comment: To the OP: your agent needs to communicate via `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, a Unix-domain socket. You'll want to start up a relay agent inside the Docker instance, I think, although since you're passing so much straight through, you might be able to just pass the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` itself through (I'm not sure if this works).

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes, it obviously in a Docker container, because I need a custom env for my Ubuntu. `git` command works on my host shell perfectly.

@torek, you are right!! Adding this `-e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK \` to my docker run script solves this issue. Your are my hero today!

Comment: @torek, please post this as an answer, and I can mark it as the solution. Printing out the value of the variable it shows /tmp/ssh-xxx/agent.<pid> in my Docker container. Whereas in the host, it contains `/run/user/<uid>/keyring/ssh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *this particular case*, you can just pass the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable across your docker instance by ([as you noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69000054/git-permission-denied-on-docker-container-with-private-key?noredirect=1#comment121950922_69000054)) adding:

```
-e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

In more general cases, where you don't have the same `/tmp` and `/home` mounts in the Docker instance, this won't work, so more generally you might have to have another ssh key, or do something fancier to pass the agent communications link through.  But here you're running in the same networking space, on the same file system, so it suffices to get your inner "virtual machine"<sup>1</sup> to use your outer (real) machine's ssh agent to get the private key.

---

<sup>1</sup>A Docker instance is more like a FreeBSD "jail" than a true VM.  Both, however, provide a sort of "poor man's VM".